# Value from JQuery populated field not binding to MVC model

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm working on a project with ASP.NET MVC, using Razor. Once the form finishes loading on the page, I expect the user triggers `.on ('change')` in an input. Once this happens, an AJAX call is executed, returning the user's data, disabling and filling the inputs that are linked to the properties of a model that starts empty (when the page is loaded).

The data is filling up without problems, but when I send it back to the controller to be processed, the values that correspond to the inputs that were filled after the AJAX execution arrive as null.

```
<div class="form-label-group col-md-4 mb-3">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AttendeeName, new { @class = "upside-label", @for = "firstName" })
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AttendeeName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "firstName", @placeholder = Resources.ResourcesPerson.PlaceholderPersonName } })
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AttendeeName, new { @class = "downside-label", @for = "firstName" })
    <div class="text-danger">
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AttendeeName)
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried the following without success:

```
$("input[name=AttendeeName]").attr('disabled', true);
$("input[name=AttendeeName]").val(data.AttendeeName).change()
```

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: This is expected behaviour. `disabled` elements are not sent in form data. If you still want those values to be sent, don't disable the fields. Possibly try `readonly` instead, if you don't want users to edit them

Comment: I have completely forgotten ... I have become too complicated with something very simple hahaha. You gave with the correct answer, put your comment as an answer to mark it as a solution. Thank you very much @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: No problem at all. I added it for you

Comment: If you want to disable a field, use `$("selector").attr("disabled", "disabled")`. `disabled` is a boolean property, meaning it's `true` when it exists, and `false` when it doesn't exists. Alternatively, you can use `$("selector).prop("disabled", true)`, which accesses the element's DOM object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. `disabled` elements are not sent in form data.

If you still want those values to be sent, don't disable the fields. Possibly try `readonly` instead, assuming that you don't want users to edit the fields:

```
$('input[name="AttendeeName"]').prop('readonly', true);
```